# efficient read of EXIF meta-data from remote images using Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, exif

I have a few thousand high-res JPEG photos stored on a travel blog website, and I'm hoping to write some Ruby code that will extract a few key EXIF meta-data values from the images *without* downloading the entire contents of each image file (they are large, and I have a LOT of them).

I'm using the 'exifr' gem to read the EXIF data, and it is designed to work with any type of IO object, not just local files. However, the `Net::HTTPResponse` object isn't really an IO object, although it does allow for incremental reading if you pass the `read_body` method a block. I've read conflicting reports, however, about whether this increment reading really allows you to only download a portion of a file, or whether it just lets you read the contents in chunks for efficiency (i.e. the entire contents is downloaded anyway).

So, is what I'm trying to do possible? Should I be looking at alternatives to `Net::HTTP`, or is there some way for me to get at the low-level TCP socket (which should be an IO object) to pass to the 'exifr' code to read just enough of the image to get the EXIF data? Other solutions?

Comment: I took a quick skim of the [Wikipedia article on JPEG compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) and I wonder if the EXIF packets are even located in a 'reliable' position in the files? A given camera might be predictable, but I don't think you could reliably expect the EXIF data to be at the end or at the beginning of the files... it'd be helpful if you could find out the byte offsets for the EXIF data on the files that you have to see if it is similar enough for some heuristics...

Answer (score 2):

I generated a quick table of where, in my pile of photos, the EXIF data is stored:

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep -a -bo Exif {} \; > /tmp/exif
$ sort /tmp/exif  | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 12306:Exif
      1 3271386:Exif
      1 8210:Exif
      1 8234:Exif
      1 9234:Exif
      2 10258:Exif
     24 449:Exif
     30 24:Exif
   8975 6:Exif
$
```

The clear majority are just a few bytes into the file; a handful are scattered elsewhere, but the worst is only three megabytes into the file. (Give or take.)

I wrote a little test script that appears to do what it necessary for a single URL. (Tested by looking for the string `AA` in chunks of a huge binary file I had available.) This certainly isn't the prettiest program I've written, but it might be an adequate start to a solution. Note that if the `Exif` text spans the chunks, you're going to retrieve the entire file. That's unfortunate. I hope it doesn't happen often. The `66000` is there because the JPEG AAP1 block is limited in size to 64 kilobytes and grabbing a bit more is probably better than grabbing a bit less.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse("http://....")

begin
    looking = true
    extra_size = 0
    File.open("/tmp/output", "w") do |f|
            Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
                    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new url.request_uri
                    http.request request do |resp|
                            resp.read_body do |chunk|
                                    f.write chunk
                                    if (looking)
                                            if (chunk.match(/Exif/))
                                                    looking = false
                                            end
                                    elsif (extra_size < 66000)
                                            extra_size += chunk.length
                                    else
                                            throw "done"
                                    end
                            end
                    end
            end
    end
rescue
    puts "done"
    exit(0)
end
```

Comment: This is so awesome. How do we use this to feed into a program though like another Exif gem that expects a file? Do I have access to the full 'partial file' up to that point within `chunk` or something? Can i treat that like a file?